# Why does Camunda not show Message Event Subscriptions at the beginning of a User Task, but at the end?

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

My model works the following way: If a business error occurs, it jumps to a User task, in which an Administrator handles the error.

I want to notify the customer (via an external tool) that their problem is being

- registered, when the User Task is created;
- looked at, when the User Task is assinged;
- solved, when the User Task is completed;
- omitted (because it is unsolvable), when the User Task is deleted.

The User Task has a boundary event for a message. And the parent process as well. I try message correlation then. But it does not have any effect because it does not show me any Message Event subscriptions in the "created" stage of the task.

Answer (score 0):

A taskListener "onCreate" gets called during the transaction where the task is created. so from inside this transaction, you can not access state that is modified from within the same transaction (like message subscription).

But I wonder: why do you have a boundary event at the user task? Why do you need to access its subscription?

The four use cases you described (onCreate/onAssign/onComplete/onCancel) can all be realized by attaching TaskListeners to the userTask, no need for boundary events.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think I misunderstood how to use the boundary. I removed it in my current iteration anyways. Yet, this still does not solve the problem, that it didn't see the subscription for the parent process, which had a non-interrupting Message Boundary. This should have been created even beforehand (because I am already in the subprocess) and be visible, right?